# How to change slidesPerview on button click and screen size change with Swiper.js and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I want to implement a button that can change the number of `slidesPerView`. A screenshot of the layout:

[image]

For example, when I click `5`, the number of `slidesPerView` changes to `5`. How can I achieve that?

I've tried to implement it this way, but it didn't work:

```
const slidesPerViewOptions = [3, 5, 7]

const changeSlidesPerView = (option: number) => {
  swiperRef.params.slidesPerView = option
}

<div>
  {slidesPerViewOptions.map((option) => (
    <button
      key={option}
      onClick={() => changeSlidesPerView(option)}
    >
      {option}
    </button>
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a proper re-render, I would use a state called `slidePerview`, for example. And here is an example of a setup:

```js
const [slidePerview, setSlidePerview] = useState(1);

const changeSlidesPerView = (option) => {
  setSlidePerview(option);
};
```

```js
<Swiper
  slidesPerView={slidePerview}
  ....
```

And if you want to also update it according to screen size change,

```
useEffect(() => {
  const checkScreenSize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 750) {
      setSlidePerview(1);
    } else if (window.innerWidth < 1080) {
      setSlidePerview(3);
    } else {
      setSlidePerview(5);
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("resize", checkScreenSize);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", checkScreenSize);
}, []);
```

[image]

Comment: While your solution works nicely, I still have a situation. I have to set the initial `slidesPerView` to "1" (for mobile screen), and then utilize the `breakpoints` prop to set the slidesPerView to `slidesPerViewState` (3, 5, or 7) on larger screen. And when the state changes, the slidesPerView doesn't seem to update. What's the workaround for this?

Comment: For window resizing, you could use an event listener. Take a look at my just edited response and let me know.